# using AUScheduleParameterBlock from a host on AUAudioUnit v3

Tags: ios, ios9, core-audio, audiounit, avaudioengine

I am new AUAudioUnits and trying to get an understanding of how to use the v3 API. I am trying to schedule a parameter change on a `kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer` AUAudioUnit so that I can ramp a gain change over time. 
I am able to set the gain directly with a slider and the change takes affect immediately like this:

```
/*...*/
// Inside my ViewController

  @IBAction func slider1Changed(sender: UISlider) {
    player.gainParameter.setValue(sender.value, originator: nil)
  }

// Inside my AudioPlayerClass

    guard let parameterTree = self.multichannelMixer.parameterTree else {
      print("Param Tree")
      return
    }

    self.gainParameter = parameterTree.parameterWithID(
      kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume,
      scope: kAudioUnitScope_Input,
      element: 0)
```

but when I try to do this using the `scheduleParameterBlock` by adding this to the above AudioPlayerClass I would expect the gain to ramp from 1 to 0 over 10 seconds but there is no change:

```
    let scheduleMixerParamBlock = self.multichannelMixer.scheduleParameterBlock
    let rampTime = AUAudioFrameCount(10.secondsToSampleFrames)
    scheduleMixerParamBlock(AUEventSampleTimeImmediate, rampTime, self.gainParameter.address, 0)
```

Examples I have seen of it working in the apple examples include code such as this (without the dispatch_async part):

```
parameterTree.implementorValueObserver = {param, value in
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print(param, value)
  }
  scheduleMixerParamBlock(AUEventSampleTimeImmediate, rampTime, param.address, value)
}
```

When I run this and change the gain parameter with the slider then the block is run and the `param` and `value` are printed to the console with the correct looking values but the gain is not changed in the actual audio.
These examples I have seen are also on custom AUAudioUnits where the implementor has direct access to the dspKernel function so I might be missing something crucial there.
The other alternative I have to calculate a series of ramp values and then set the gain parameter directly for each value but since the `scheduleParameterBlock` is there is seems like I should be able to use that. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: 3 years on and I'm seeing exactly the same thing - nothing happens! Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the `AURenderEvent` head in the `internalRenderBlock` which is operating on the audio render thread. Your scheduled parameter events will appear there for you to respond to.

For example, pass the head to this function:

```
void doEvents(AURenderEvent const* event)
    {
        while (event != nullptr) {
            switch (event->head.eventType) {
                case AURenderEventParameter:
                    doParameterEvent(event->parameter);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            event = event->head.next;
        }
    }

void doParameterEvent(AUParameterEvent const &event) {
        switch (event.parameterAddress) {
            case FilterParameterAddressFoo:
                doFoo();
                break;
            case FilterParameterAddressBar:
                doBar();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```